# How to again display vanished icon from my form?

Tags: vb.net, icons

i am using this code for form display in my form load event but after form load icon of the form vanished i want to show my icon please help me 
Here is the code:

```
Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None 'Turning off border
Me.SetBounds(meleft, metop, Me.Width, MinimumSize.Height) 'setting the loaction and the size of the  form

    For i As Integer = 0 To meheight Step 20
        If (Me.Height < meheight) Then
            Me.Top = Me.Top - 20
            Me.Height = Me.Height + 20

            Me.Refresh()

            For FadeCount = 40 To 40 Step 20
                Me.Opacity = FadeCount / 100

                Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
            Next
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Me.Height = meheight
    Me.Top = (msize(1, 1) - Me.Height) / 2 + msize(1, 3)
    Me.Opacity = 99
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
```

Comment: Which icon are you talking about? The one in the top left corner? Because that one is probably part of your border style, which you are explicitly setting to none.

Comment: yes i am talking about top left corner in the title bar icon. I am not setting any icon property to none but if this is happening by it self could you please tell me how to get it back.

Comment: Just don't change the FormBorderStyle property.

Comment: Alternatively you could probably get away with placing a `PictureBox` where the icon used to be. Not sure how you would wire that up to the application's icon though.

Answer (score 0):

At the start of the code you declare:

**Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None**

This is what is making your border/icon not visible.

Answer (score 0):

In Form1 Properties-->Window Style: Set ControlBox = True.